SSL connection error: unknown error number QMYSQL: Unable to connect
I am new to QT development. I am trying to connect with mysql database from the qt application but getting ssl connection error. Below is the code snippet.
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>

void connectToDatabase() {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("aditya");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("aditya");
    db.setPort(3306);

    qDebug() << "Hello4";
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Error: connection with database fail:" << db.lastError().text();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Database: connection ok";
    }
}

void executeQuery() {
    QSqlQuery query;
    if (query.exec("SELECT * FROM test")) {
        while (query.next()) {
            QString name = query.value("name").toString();
            qDebug() << "Name:" << name;
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Query failed:" << query.lastError().text();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    connectToDatabase();
    executeQuery();

    return a.exec();
}

Getting below error while running the program
Error: connection with database fail: "SSL connection error: unknown error number QMYSQL: Unable to connect"
Any leads will be appreciated.
Thanks

you can try disabling SSL in your client configuration to see if that allows you to connect:
db.setConnectOptions("SSL_MODE=DISABLED"); or maybe you need to configure options for db connection e.g.
db.setConnectOptions("SSL_KEY=/path_to_client-key.pem;SSL_CERT=/path_to_client-cert.pem;SSL_CA=/path_to_ca-cert.pem");

I tried using db.setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_SSL_MODE=SSL_MODE_DISABLED") but still getting same SSL connection error. Can you please help me with how can I generate SSL_KEY, SSL_CERT and SSL_CA as I do not have these

So I tried skip_ssl in my.ini file and it worked for me, the issue is resolved
